# Incorrectly saved file lost during recent update - cannot find anywhere

Tags: microsoft-word, path, updates

I had a Word .docx file in process, mistakenly saved to documents in quick access instead of documents in C:drive. An update came through and when I went to open the file the error said it had no path, was either moved, renamed or deleted. I have looked in recycling, searched the drives, no where to be found. Any possible way to recover my work?

Comment: Add to your question the answer to: What OS? Add a tag for your OS.

Answer (score 0):

Look in Word, Options, Save for the Auto Recover location and look there for a prior version.

Quick Access is a pointer, not a location, so nothing is stored there. But if you looked where QA pointed to and the document is not there, then the Auto Recover location is likely your only hope.

Comment: You have pinpointed my challenge. I accidentally saved it in Quick Access instead of the C drive, which, as you pointed out is not a location, therefore any search is coming up empty. If I did the auto recover, is there a chance it may still be there? The computer has since rebooted, so I'm afraid it is gone forever - hate these automatic updates - no warning, just reboot and everything is closed...Please advise. thank you!

Comment: Yes the document is gone so there is not much you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you've saved your document? If so, you should be able to find it directly in your MS Word application in the recent document (if you can't remember the name) - as explained by John.

Also, normally with Windows 10 you should see in your **Quick Access** the last documents. See following picture:

Your Recent Files:

[image: Recent Files].

If this option is not activated for you, you can also open a File Explorer and type in the address bar the following sentence `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\`

It will show you all the recent files and document you've used. If it's not removed and it really exists, you should be able to find it in this list.

Answer (score 0):

When after saving the file it was just moved to another location on a local drive, I would use the tool [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com) or [UltraSearch](https://www.jam-software.de/ultrasearch), search for all `".docx"` files very fast because both tools read the `MFT` and then sort the results by the `"changed"`  column (`"Geändert am"`).

[image: 1]